# Iterating through nested JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

first time posting here.
Having trouble getting into a JSON, and I could use some active.

The data that I need is at this level:

```
restaurant["menu"][0]["children"][0]["name"]

restaurant["menu"][0]["children"][0]["id"]
```

I want an array of "id"s based on "name"s.

This is the method that I'm working with:

```
def find_burgers(rest)

    array = []

    rest["menu"].each do |section| 
    section["children"].each do |innersection| 
    innersection["name"].downcase.split.include?("burger")
    array.push(innersection["id"]) 
    end
  end   
  return array
end
```

As you can imagine, I'm getting back an array of every "id", not just the "id"s for burgers.  I've tried many combinations of .map and .keep_if.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: This is one menu item:

```
{
    "children" => [
    [ 0] {
        "availability" => [
            [0] 0
        ],
            "children" => [
            [0] {
                             "children" => [
                    [0] {
                        "availability" => [
                            [0] 0
                        ],
                             "descrip" => "",
                                  "id" => "50559491",
                        "is_orderable" => "1",
                                "name" => "Single",
                               "price" => "0.00"
                    },
                    [1] {
                        "availability" => [
                            [0] 0
                        ],
                             "descrip" => "",
                                  "id" => "50559492",
                        "is_orderable" => "1",
                                "name" => "Double",
                               "price" => "2.25"
                    }
                ],
                              "descrip" => "What Size Would You Like?",
                    "free_child_select" => "0",
                                   "id" => "50559490",
                         "is_orderable" => "0",
                     "max_child_select" => "1",
                "max_free_child_select" => "0",
                     "min_child_select" => "1",
                                 "name" => "Milk Burger Size"
            },
            [1] {
                             "children" => [
                    [0] {
                        "availability" => [
                            [0] 0
                        ],
                             "descrip" => "",
                                  "id" => "50559494",
                        "is_orderable" => "1",
                                "name" => "Bacon",
                               "price" => "2.00"
                    }
                ],
                              "descrip" => "Add",
                    "free_child_select" => "0",
                                   "id" => "50559493",
                         "is_orderable" => "0",
                     "max_child_select" => "1",
                "max_free_child_select" => "0",
                     "min_child_select" => "0",
                                 "name" => "Burgr Ad Bacon Optn"
            }
        ],
             "descrip" => "American cheese, lettuce, tomato and Milk Sauce",
                  "id" => "50559489",
        "is_orderable" => "1",
                "name" => "Milk Burger",
               "price" => "4.25"
    },
```

Comment: Can you also post the JSON/parsed hash?

Comment: I'll post one above.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can iterate through a nested hash like this:

```
def iterate(h)
  h.each do |k, v| 
    if v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)
      iterate(v)
    else
      puts("k is #{k}, value is #{v}")
    end
  end
end
```

But since you have the concrete, hardcoded names `children, name`, etc, it seems there's only way to do that is the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

A little more accurate answer that iterates over Hashes or Arrays in JSON

```
j = {'key$1' => 'asdada',
     'key$2' => ['key$3' => 2,
                 'key$4' => 's',
                 'key$6' => ['key$7' => 'man',
                             'key$8' => 'super']
                 ],
     'key5' => 5 }

def iterate(i)
  if i.is_a?(Hash)
    i.each do |k, v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)
        puts("k is #{k}, value is #{v}")
        iterate(v)
      else
        puts("k is #{k}, value is #{v}")
      end
    end
  end
  if i.is_a?(Array)
    i.each do |v|
      iterate(v)
    end
  end
end

iterate(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're performing a test to see if the name contains "burger" but you're not doing anything with the result of the test. Try this instead:

```
def find_burgers(rest)

  array = []

  rest["menu"].each do |section| 
    section["children"].each do |innersection| 
      array.push(innersection["id"]) if innersection["name"].downcase.split.include?("burger")
    end
  end   
  return array
end
```

Also, consider using a regular expression instead of the `downcase.split.include?' like so:

```
def find_burgers(rest)

  array = []

  rest["menu"].each do |section| 
    section["children"].each do |innersection| 
      array.push(innersection["id"]) if innersection["name"] =~ /\bburger\b/i
    end
  end   
  return array
end
```

The regular expression returns true if the name contains the string "burger" surrounded by word-breaks (\b) ignoring case (/i).

And finally (I think) you could use a more functional approach like so:

```
def find_burgers(rest)
  rest["menu"].map do |section| 
    section["children"].select do |innersection| 
      innersection["name"] =~ /\bburger\b/i
    end
  end.flatten.map {|item| item["id"] }
end
```

The `select` returns only those items that match the regular expression, the first `map` passes back an array of matching innersections for each `section`, the flatten turns the array of arrays into a simple array, and the final map picks out just the `id` from each innersection.

I think I've gone too far.

Comment: That did it!  I'm new to writing code, and I spent (wasted?) of time on this, so I really appreciate it.

Comment: Cool! Keep at it -- it gets easier. And please consider accepting my answer if it's what you needed.